# A custom-made right angle mark that does not seem to be drawn correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf

With the accompanying code, the foot of the altitude of triangle $PQR$ from $R$ is labeled $G$. The coordinates is calculated from the following command.

```
\coordinate (G) at ($(P)!(R)!(Q)$);
```

I construct an auxiliary point $V$ in order to draw the right-angle mark.

```
\coordinate (V) at ($(G)!3.75mm!-45:(P)$);
\draw ($(P)!(V)!(G)$) -- (V) -- ($(R)!(V)!(G)$);
```

To me, the right-angle mark at $G$ does not look perpendicular to the sides. In particular, it does not look perpendicular to side $\overline{\mathit{GP}}$. Is this merely an optical illusion?

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}




\begin{document}


\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}


%A triangle is drawn.
\coordinate (P) at (12,0);
\coordinate (Q) at ($(P) +(120:2/5*6)$);
\coordinate (R) at ($(Q) +({2/5*(-7.5)},0)$);
\draw (P) -- (Q) -- (R) -- cycle;

%The labels for the vertices are typeset.
\path let \p1=($(P)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in  node[anchor={0.5*(\n1-60)+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(P) +({0.5*(\n1-60)}:0.15)$){$P$};
\path node[anchor=west, inner sep=0] at ($(Q) +(0.15,0)$){$Q$};
\path node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(R) +(-0.15,0)$){$R$};


%The foot of the altitude from R is located.
\coordinate (G) at ($(P)!(R)!(Q)$);
\node[anchor={0.5*(30+120)+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(G) +({0.5*(30+120)}:0.15)$){$G$};


%A right-angle mark is drawn at G.
\coordinate (V) at ($(G)!3.75mm!-45:(P)$);
\path[fill=yellow] ($(P)!(V)!(G)$) -- (V) -- ($(R)!(V)!(G)$) -- (G) -- cycle;
\draw ($(P)!(V)!(G)$) -- (V) -- ($(R)!(V)!(G)$);
\draw[dashed] (G) -- (Q);
\draw[dashed] (G) -- (R);



\draw[name path=arc_to_mark_angle_at_P,draw=blue] let \p1=($(P)-(Q)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(P)-(R)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in ($(P)!5mm!(Q)$) arc ({\n1-180}:{\n2-180}:0.5);
\draw[blue] let \p1=($(P)-(Q)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(P)-(R)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in ($(P) +({0.5*(\n1+\n2)-180}:{0.5cm-3pt})$) -- ($(P) +({0.5*(\n1+\n2)-180}:{0.5cm+3pt})$);


\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am unsure what you mean, but to me the line *G͞P* is exactly orthogonal to the line *G͞R*.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht Yes, those line segments look perpendicular. To me, the line segments enclosing the yellow square do not look perpendicular to those line segments.

Comment: I think they are correct. You can double check with `\path[fill=red, rotate={120}] (V) rectangle (G);` which would produce a square (where the opposite sides are guaranteed to be parallel) that should exactly cover the yellow area.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht Actually, that command affirms that the line segments enclosing the yellow square are not perpendicular to G͞P and  G͞R.

Comment: Then, I fear I don't understand what you are talking about, sorry. To me the angle at *G* is 90 degrees and the yellow area is a square. Maybe we are talking about different things. Could you maybe add a picture that shows the output you get and where you think the problem appears?

Comment: @Jasper Habicht  Add these two commands at the end of the code.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht  \path[fill=red, rotate={120}] (V) rectangle (G);

Comment: @Jasper Habicht  \draw ($(P)!(V)!(G)$) -- (V) -- ($(R)!(V)!(G)$);

Comment: @Jasper Habicht Compile it, and magnify the diagram by 300%.

Comment: Sorry, but my output looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re53a.png I cannot find anything wrong with it.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht  Thanks for sharing your output. That is what I was **expecting** but not getting. I have found over the years that the editor on personal computer does not always accurately locate points declared with commands like `($(P)!(V)!(G)$)`. It is so annoying! In case you are interested, I posted an alternate code to draw the right-angle mark.

Comment: The editor is surely not to blame, but you should check that your TeX installation is up-to-date. But actually, I am unsure why exactly the output could actually be like you describe. From your answer, I would guess, that it is somehow related to Ti*k*Z' `calc` library.

Comment: Please add your output as an image to your question. Please check what version of MikTeX you use and PGF/TikZ (via `\pgfversion`). Something's very wrong if you don't get the same output as @JasperHabicht. By the way, there's a [`right angle`](https://tikz.dev/library-angle) available where you don't need to do anything manual.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel How do I add the the pdf to my post? Where do I enter `\pgfversion`?

Comment: Take a screenshot. And use the image upload tool when editing your question (Ctrl+G). `\pgfversion` is a normal macro that can be used in normal text, i.e. somewhere between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document0}`. I suspect an outdated version of PGF/TikZ or your TeX distribution or, at worst, a broken installation.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel
 I included a screenshot to my post.

Comment: @Jasper Habicht I included a screenshot to my post.

Answer (score 1):

The `angles` library provides two pics (`angle` and `right angle`) which we can use to mark angles and also to add a label to a corner without having to calculate all the angles ourselves.

Instead of text, we can also use another pic (here `vert`) to mark an angle.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, calc}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  pics/mark corner/.style args={#1--#2--#3}{
    /tikz/angle radius=0pt, /tikz/angle eccentricity=0, /tikz/pic text={$#2$},
    /tikz/pic text options={circle, inner sep=+.15em, anchor=.5*\tikz@start@angle@temp+.5*\tikz@end@angle@temp},
    angle={#1--#2--#3}},
  pics/mark angle with pic/.style={
    /tikz/angle eccentricity=1,
    /tikz/pic text options={pic, rotate=90+.5*\tikz@start@angle@temp+.5*\tikz@end@angle@temp},
    angle={#1}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  pic/.is if=tikz@node@is@pic,
  pics/vert/.style={% nested pics need care
    setup code=, background code=, foreground code=,
    code=\draw (down:1mm) -- (up:1mm);},
  pics/right angle/.prefix style={/tikz/angle radius=2.65mm},%3.75mm/sqrt2
  angle radius=5mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (12,0)       coordinate (P)
    ++(120:2/5*6)  coordinate[label=right:$Q$] (Q)
    ++(-2/5*7.5,0) coordinate[label=left:$R$]  (R)
    coordinate (G) at ($(P)!(R)!(Q)$);
\foreach \c in {R--G--P, Q--P--R}
  \pic {mark corner/.expanded=\c};

\pic[draw, fill=yellow]                 {right angle = R--G--P};
\pic[draw, blue, pic text=vert] {mark angle with pic = Q--P--R};

\draw (P) -- (Q) -- (R) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] (Q) -- (G) -- (R);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the conversation that I have been having with Jasper Habicht, it is apparent that the MikTex on my personal computer does not accurately compile certain commands. In this case, the commands to locate the coordinates for `($(P)!(V)!(G)$)` and `($(R)!(V)!(G)$)` were not quite right.

I am posting an alternate code that I am using to draw a right-angle mark at point $G$.

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}




\begin{document}


\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}


%A triangle is drawn.
\coordinate (P) at (12,0);
\coordinate (Q) at ($(P) +(120:2/5*6)$);
\coordinate (R) at ($(Q) +({2/5*(-7.5)},0)$);
\draw (P) -- (Q) -- (R) -- cycle;

%The labels for the vertices are typeset.
\path let \p1=($(P)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in  node[anchor={0.5*(\n1-60)+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(P) +({0.5*(\n1-60)}:0.15)$){$P$};
\path node[anchor=west, inner sep=0] at ($(Q) +(0.15,0)$){$Q$};
\path node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(R) +(-0.15,0)$){$R$};


%The foot of the altitude from R is located.
\coordinate (G) at ($(P)!(R)!(Q)$);
\node[anchor={0.5*(30+120)+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(G) +({0.5*(30+120)}:0.15)$){$G$};


%A right-angle mark is drawn at G.
\coordinate (V) at ($(G)!3.75mm!-45:(P)$);
%\path[fill=yellow] ($(P)!(V)!(G)$) -- (V) -- ($(R)!(V)!(G)$) -- (G) -- cycle;
%\draw ($(P)!(V)!(G)$) -- (V) -- ($(R)!(V)!(G)$);


  \path[fill=red, rotate={120}] (V) rectangle (G);
  \draw ($(P)!(V)!(G)$) -- (V) -- ($(R)!(V)!(G)$);
  \path let \p1=($(G)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in coordinate (V_1) at ($(V) +(\n1:1)$);
  \path coordinate (V_2) at ($(V) +(120:1)$);
  \coordinate (W_1) at (intersection of G--P and V--V_1);
  \coordinate (W_2) at (intersection of G--R and V--V_2);
  \path[fill=yellow] (W_1) -- (V) -- (W_2) -- (G) -- cycle;
  \draw (W_1) -- (V) -- (W_2);
  \draw[dashed] (G) -- (Q);
  \draw[dashed] (G) -- (R);


\draw[name path=arc_to_mark_angle_at_P,draw=blue] let \p1=($(P)-(Q)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(P)-(R)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in ($(P)!5mm!(Q)$) arc ({\n1-180}:{\n2-180}:0.5);
\draw[blue] let \p1=($(P)-(Q)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)}, \p2=($(P)-(R)$), \n2={atan(\y2/\x2)} in ($(P) +({0.5*(\n1+\n2)-180}:{0.5cm-3pt})$) -- ($(P) +({0.5*(\n1+\n2)-180}:{0.5cm+3pt})$);


\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}




\end{document}
```